# How do I describe an inline && in English?

Tags: actionscript-3, operators

I recently came across some code like this:

```
parent && parent.removeChild(this);
```

Which takes the place of:

```
if(parent)
    parent.removeChild(this);
```

I see how it works, I'm just having a lot of trouble explaining the syntax to myself in plain English so that I can implement it elsewhere (I guess I don't fully understand what's happening, I just know how it works in this particular case). For example, the below which I use often reads easily to me as *"value is a or b (in the absence of a)"*.

```
var url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.url || "http://test.com/";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it as this:

> Execute the statement on the right hand side if and only if the
>   statement on the left hand side returns a true value.

Comment: Works for me.. Just seems weird because `&&` reads as AND to me so it's like `property and run method` without much meaningful context.

Comment: It is AND, but you have to read it like this: _if left AND right returns true_ - so if either of the conditions on the left or right of the operator fails, then the entire statement (line of code, fails). "Returns true" means any _truth value_, which usually means a positive integer.